# Bluemix Single Sign On service: Node.js code for getting the currently logged in userid?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix's Single Sign On service from a Node.js runtime, which is working fine. But now, I would like to access the userid of the user that is logged into the app. I can't find how in the [docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html) or any API or way to do it.

Any help or sample about how to do it? I found some serialize and deserialize user functions within passport object, but really don't know how to use them (if really they do what I am looking for).

Answer (score 1):

It seems `req.session.passport.user.id` did the trick.

Comment: Can you post your use of serialize and deserialize here and the call to the auth strategy so others can find it as well?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I didn't do anything special, just cut and paste the code from the docs: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index-gentopic2.html#task_configuringapp and then using the commented piece of code in the answer I am able to get the userid.